# Use docker image from private external registry in AWS ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I am trying to run an image in AWS ECS hosted in my company's private registry. According to AWS, this is entirely possible as long as I use the guide from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/private-auth.html and follow the section `Enabling private registry authentication`. I have created a secret in AWS Secrets Manager called `testSecret` in plaintext format with the json structure provided in the link above, like:

```json
{
  "username": "myuser",
  "password": "mypass"
}
```

I reference it in my ECS job definition in the `Secrets` section with the name `myRegistryCreds` and then enter the ARN value of the secret above in the `Value From` section.

Whenever I try to run the job though, I get the error below:

```
CannotPullContainerError: Error response from daemon: Head "https://myprivateregistry.com/myrepo/helloworld/manifests/latest": no basic auth credentials
```

The policy attached to my execution role mimics what is in the AWS guide as well:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "kms:Decrypt",
                "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:secretsmanager:<awsRegion>:<myAWSaccount>:secret:testSecret-CtEe8E",
                "arn:aws:kms:*:<myAWSaccount>:key/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**My working task definition:**

```json
{
"containerDefinitions": [
    {
        "name": "default",
        "image": "myprivatregistry.com/repo/helloworld:latest",
        "repositoryCredentials": {
            "credentialsParameter": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:AWSACCOUNT:role:secret:REGISTRYKEY"
        },
        "cpu": 2,
        "memory": 1000,
        "portMappings": [],
        "essential": true,
        "environment": [],
        "mountPoints": [],
        "volumesFrom": [],
        "linuxParameters": {
            "tmpfs": []
        },
        "logConfiguration": {
            "logDriver": "awslogs",
            "options": {
                "awslogs-group": "/aws/batch/job",
                "awslogs-region": "us-east-1",
                "awslogs-stream-prefix": "hello-world"
            }
        }
    }
],
"family": "hello-world",
"executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::AWSACCOUNT:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole"
}
```

Does anyone know what I am missing / how to use an image from an external, private registry in AWS ECS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Secrets Manager encrypts secrets by default - no option to store "plain text".
Check if task execution role has `kms:Decrypt` action allowed.

Based on added task definition, you are missing the `repositoryCredentials` section in `containerDefinitions` array.

Should be:

```
{
    "taskDefinition": {
        "taskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:aws-region:awsAccount:task-definition/my-task-definition:7",
        "containerDefinitions": [
            {
                "name": "default",
                "image": "myprivateregistry.com/myrepo/helloworld/manifests/latest",
                "repositoryCredentials": {
                    "credentialsParameter": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:aws-region:awsAccount:secret:testSecret-CtEe8E"
                },
                "cpu": 0,
                "memory": 1,
                "portMappings": [],
                "essential": true,
                "environment": [],
                "mountPoints": [],
                "volumesFrom": [],
                "linuxParameters": {
                    "tmpfs": []
                },
                "secrets": null,
                "logConfiguration": {
                    "logDriver": "awslogs",
                    "options": {
                        "awslogs-group": "/aws/batch/job",
                        "awslogs-region": "aws-region",
                        "awslogs-stream-prefix": "my-task-definition"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "family": "my-task-definition",
        "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::awsAccount:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
        "networkMode": "host",
        "revision": 7,
        "volumes": [],
        "status": "ACTIVE",
        "requiresAttributes": [
            {
                "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.logging-driver.awslogs"
            },
            {
                "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-awslogs"
            },
            {
                "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.19"
            },
            {
                "name": "ecs.capability.secrets.asm.environment-variables"
            },
            {
                "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.22"
            },
            {
                "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.18"
            }
        ],
        "placementConstraints": [],
        "compatibilities": [
            "EXTERNAL",
            "EC2"
        ],
        "registeredAt": 1643130577.733,
        "registeredBy": "arn:aws:sts::awsAccount:assumed-role/AWSServiceRoleForBatch/aws-batch"
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Tomasz, thanks for the comment. I've edited my post to include a clarification on the plaintext section and the policy used. The policy my ECS execution role uses does have `kms:Decrypt` in it.

Comment: "I reference it in my ECS job definition in the Secrets section with the name myRegistryCreds and then enter the ARN value of the secret above in the Value From section."

Something is not right here.
Repo credentials are set in Container definition in the task.
You have to check "Private repository authentication" checkbox and provide "Secrets Manager ARN or name"
Can you add your task definition to the question?

Comment: For task definition you can use https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/describe-task-definition.html

Comment: Added the task definition to my question!

Comment: Check my answer, I've added possible solution.

Comment: Solved it for me, thanks Tomasz.